# How to only allow digits and dots in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm wondering how I can get my textbox to only accept digits and dots, like:

123.45
or 115
or 218.16978

etc.

I already have the following code:

```
Private Sub TxtHStof_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtHStof.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
    
End Sub
```

But that only allows digits without the dots.

How can I change the code so it does allows the dots as well, but nothing else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OR e.KeyChar=".")
```

Comment: the back key is not working! how to add it to your code?

Comment: @OsamaGadour: To allow the backspace character to work, you need to add "Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8" to the conditional.  8 is the ascii code for the backspace character.

Comment: nearly 11 years later...this still works for VB .net...thx!

Comment: Also, want to add that, instead of comparing to the number 8, we can do this now: Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Back

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution doesn't cater for

1. Multiple entries of decimals for example "12....1234"
2. OS specific decimal separators

This works for me

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim DecimalSeparator As String = Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or
                     Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or
                     (e.KeyChar = DecimalSeparator And sender.Text.IndexOf(DecimalSeparator) = -1))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `MaskedTextBox` - see here on how to set the format string (which allows you to restrict to digits and decimal point only)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can use ',' (Europe) and '.' (American) decimals.

```
Private Sub TGewicht_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TGewicht.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or ((e.KeyChar = "." Or e.KeyChar = ",") And (sender.Text.IndexOf(".") = -1 And sender.Text.IndexOf(",") = -1)))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    '****To Allow only Numbers with Decimal and BACKSPACE enabled****
    If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ".") And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from C# and not VB, I'm taking a stab at this, but would this work:

```
e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar.Equals('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert function in MODULE o FORM

```
Public Sub OnlyNumber(Ct As TextBox, MaxLength As Integer)
    Ct.MaxLength = MaxLength
    AddHandler Ct.KeyPress, AddressOf ValidarTeclaNumeros
End Sub

Private Sub ValidarTeclaNumeros(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim Ct As TextBox
    Ct = sender
    If [Char].IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse [Char].IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        'ok 
        'e.Handled = True
    ElseIf [Char].IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) Then
        If (Ct.Text.Contains(",") OrElse Ct.Text.Contains(".")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If


    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If


End Sub
```

In load form add this code for your control only numerical (and only one comma or doc)

```
OnlyNumber(txtControl, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I started with mostly the same question, but I did care about being able to paste. While searching on the web for how to do this, I found that I really should handle:

1. Periods or commas as the decimal indicator, depending on how your OS is set up.
2. Only allowing keypresses that conform to the pattern, while still allowing cursor control characters like arrows and backspace.
3. Only allowing pastes into the TextBox that conform to the pattern. I chose to this in a manner that, when pasting, the code treats the pasted text as if the text was being keyed in, so pasting "a1b.c2d,e3f.g4h,i5j" into the TextBox would show up as "1.2345" if periods are your decimal indicator, and "12,345" if commas are your decimal indicator.

I tried the MaskedTextBox and really did not like it, as it enforced the decimal point location where I really just wanted to be able to freely fill in any numeric. I may have gone a little overboard using a RegEx for the pattern matching, but now I should be able to reuse this code pretty much anywhere.

```
Public Class frmMain

    Dim RegexValidator As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
    Dim FormLoaded As Boolean = False

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim RegexDecimalPattern As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
        RegexDecimalPattern = IIf(RegexDecimalPattern = ".", "\.", RegexDecimalPattern)
        RegexValidator = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d*" & RegexDecimalPattern & "?\d*$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        FormLoaded = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        ' Code below is based on
        ' http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?626378-how-to-validate-textbox-allows-only-numeric-and-decimal-in-vb-net
        ' but was modified to be based on Regex patterns.
        '
        ' Note that:
        ' KeyPress event validation covers data entry as it is being typed.
        ' TextChanged event validation covers data entry by cut/pasting.
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            'Allow all control characters.
        Else
            Dim Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
            Dim SelectionStart = Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart
            Dim SelectionLength = Me.TextBox1.SelectionLength
            Text = Text.Substring(0, SelectionStart) & e.KeyChar & Text.Substring(SelectionStart + SelectionLength)
            If Not RegexValidator.IsMatch(Text) Then e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ' If default text is used in a textbox, a TextChanged event occurs before 
        ' RegexValidator is initialized during the Form Load, so we need to check. 
        If FormLoaded Then
            ' Note that:
            ' KeyPress event validation covers data entry as it is being typed.
            ' TextChanged event validation covers data entry by cut/pasting.
            Dim Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
            Dim ValidatedText As String = ""
            Dim KeyChar As Char
            For Each KeyChar In Text
                If RegexValidator.IsMatch(ValidatedText + KeyChar) Then ValidatedText += KeyChar
            Next
            If (ValidatedText.Length > 0) And (TextBox1.Text <> ValidatedText) Then
                Me.TextBox1.Text = ValidatedText
                Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart += ValidatedText.Length
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

im late for the party but here is my code

```
  Private Sub LoanFeeTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles LoanFeeTextBox.KeyPress
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse e.KeyChar = "."c Then
            If LoanFeeTextBox.TextLength = 12 And LoanFeeTextBox.Text.Contains(".") = False Then
                LoanFeeTextBox.AppendText(".")
            ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And LoanFeeTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                e.Handled = True
            ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
                If LoanFeeTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                    If LoanFeeTextBox.Text.Length >= LoanFeeTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then
                        e.Handled = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(
   ByVal sender As Object,
   ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs
) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = "." Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8)
End Sub
```

Comment: Even when your post, answers OP's question. Please provide not only a snippet that works. But explain what's happening, why it does what it should to etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another solution.  This code restricts user to entering only one "." decimal point, only two places beyond the decimal point, can set how many digits you want to use (currently I have it set to only allow up to to 5 whole numbers before the decimal.  Also allows use of backspace and delete.  That way they can't fat finger an extra "." and end up with something like "45.5.5".

```
If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.keyChar) OrElse e.keyChar = "."c Then


            If Amount_FundedTextBox.TextLength = 5 And Amount_FundedTextBox.Text.Contains(".") = False Then
                Amount_FundedTextBox.AppendText(".")
            ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And Amount_FundedTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                e.Handled = True
            ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
                If Amount_FundedTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                        If Amount_FundedTextBox.Text.Length >= Amount_FundedTextBox.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then
                            e.Handled = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                e.Handled = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict character entries in your textboxes by adding a "KeyPress" handler (from TextBox properties) and specifying allowable characters.  If the character is "handled" then it is not permitted.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
    Dim txt As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    If Not ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) Or (e.KeyChar = "E") Or (e.KeyChar = "e") Or (e.KeyChar = "-")) Then e.Handled = True
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then e.Handled = False 'allow Backspace
    If e.KeyChar = "." And txt.Text.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then e.Handled = False 'allow single decimal point
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then GetNextControl(txt, True).Focus() 'Enter key moves to next control
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox4_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox4.KeyPress

        ' its worked for only number with point and worked backspace 
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "." And TextBox4.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "." Then
            e.Handled = False
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
            e.Handled = False
        End If
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            If TextBox4.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                If TextBox4.Text.Length >= TextBox4.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then  'replace 2 for greater numbers after decimal point
                    e.Handled = True
                    TextBox4.Focus()
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ' is for only digit with back space 
        e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)

        If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
            e.Handled = False
        End If
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            If TextBox4.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
                If TextBox4.Text.Length >= TextBox4.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then  'replace 2 for greater numbers after decimal point
                    e.Handled = True
                    TextBox4.Focus()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
        e.Handled = True
    Else
        e.Handled = False
    End If
```